# Why is there no SingleOrDefaultAsync for IQueryables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

The following code does not compile because SingleOrDefaultAsync() is not a suitable extension for GetAppointments(). I was just wondering why ...

```
public IQueryable<Appointment> GetAppointments()
{
        return Context.Appointments;
}

public async Task<Appointment> GetAppointmentAsync(int appointmentId)
{
        return await GetAppointments().SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ID == appointmentId);
}
```

I am using EF 6.0.0. And please ignore what I am doing here exactly. I just tried to make things easier than they actually are in my project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you have added `System.Data.Entity` namespace to your usings. This is an extension method, and it will not be available until you add appropriate namespace.

Comment: Oh my god. I am so stupid. Haha. Thanks Sergey. Didn't see the forest for the trees!

Answer (score 10):

I fixed it by adding `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

Add the following statement into the module you are working on:

```cs
// using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Then using .NET CLI,

```sh
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version <version-you-want> // if ommited the latest will be installed
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

using PM:

```sh
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version <version-you-want> // if omitted the latest will be installed
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

or Package Reference:

Add on your project **.csproj** file

```
 <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="<verion>" />
 </ItemGroup>

// in the CLI
dotnet restore
```