# How can I use LINQ to just return one row from a selection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
var wordForms = await db.WordForms
   .Where(w => w.Text == word)
   .AsNoTracking()
   .ToListAsync();
```

It returns a list but there's only ever one entry as Text is unique. How can I make this just retrieve one word only?

Comment: Can you modify ToListAsync to achieve the necessary result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`FirstOrDefaultAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn218858(v=vs.113).aspx) as your final LINQ method:

```
 var wordForms = await db.WordForms
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Text == word)
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to return single element right away. I do this by:

```
//When there is multiple entries expected but I only need the first
var wordForms = await db.WordForms
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Text == word);
```

or

```
//When I am sure only one entry exist
var wordForms = await db.WordForms
           .SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Text == word);
```

If you do not need to await you can just use the default extension methods without await.

For Async SingleOrDefault and Async FirstOrDefault you must include Entity framework 6.

[Why is there no SingleOrDefaultAsync for IQueryables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259703/why-is-there-no-singleordefaultasync-for-iqueryables)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220208(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Will not work, you can only await a Task, not any other value

Comment: Edited to include Async approach

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that your terminal operation needs to be any of FirstAsync, FirstOrDefaultAsync, SingleAsync or SingleOrDefaultAsync.

I haven't checked, but I'm presuming that all of those variants exist.

Comment: Those would need implementation as a form of ToListAsync, already used

Answer (score -3):

So you just want the first value from WordForms that have Text==word?

```
var wordForms = (from c in db.WordForms
                where c.Text==word
                select c).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Where's Async-Await